# Java: Why does my components not center?

Tags: java, layout

I just began to play around with the `new GridBagLayout` and ran into a problem...

My code:
`GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();`

```
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 5, 5);
    enterNum1 = new JLabel("Enter 1. number:");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    getContentPane().add(enterNum1, gbc);
    enterNum2 = new JLabel("Enter 2. number:");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    getContentPane().add(enterNum2, gbc);

    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    num1 = new JTextField(6);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    getContentPane().add(num1, gbc);
    num1.setToolTipText("Enter a number");
    num2 = new JTextField(6);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    getContentPane().add(num2, gbc);
    num2.setToolTipText("Enter a number");

    calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    getContentPane().add(calculate, gbc);
    calculate.addActionListener(this);

    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    addCB = new JCheckBox("Addition");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    getContentPane().add(addCB, gbc);
    addCB.setToolTipText("Enable addition");
    subCB = new JCheckBox("Subtraction");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    getContentPane().add(subCB, gbc);
    subCB.setToolTipText("Enable subtraction");
    mulCB = new JCheckBox("Multiplication");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    getContentPane().add(mulCB, gbc);
    mulCB.setToolTipText("Enable multiplication");

    divCB = new JCheckBox("Division");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    getContentPane().add(divCB, gbc);
    divCB.setToolTipText("Enable division");
```

I want my check-boxes to be in the center: `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;`but it won't...
I think that is has something to do with this line `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;`

The problem is just, that I don't know how to "disable" the `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;`   for the rest of my components...